# Python - Multiplying an element from 2D list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, multiplication

I would like to multiply one of the elements from the 2D list by an integer. However, once I execute the code I get the following: I was expecting the outcome to be just a tuple, rather than a list, and would like for it to be a tuple rather than a list.

```
[3, 3, 3]
[6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

This is my code:

```
list = [[0.5],[0.3],[0.1]]

def funcOne(juv):    
    newAd = juv * list[0]
    return newAd

def funcTwo(ad,sen):
    newSen = (ad* list[1]) + (sen* list[2])
    return newSen

print(funcOne(3))
print(funcTwo(2,4))
```

My desired output for funcOne would be to have 3*0.5 = **1.5**, where "0.5" is list[0]. I am unsure about how to edit my code in order to achieve this outcome.

Comment: It is not clear. Please can you edit the question with sample input and required output in order to make it more clear for others

Comment: By default a list multiplied by a number will return a list. If you want it to return a tuple instead you will have to cast it as one. (e.g. return tuple(newAd) ). Do you actually mean a "tuple" though? I may be reading wrong, but it sounds like you were expecting a very different output.

Comment: @TripleD Hi, I have edited my code, and I **do** want one tuple output, such as 3*list[0] to output 1.5. This is because list[0] is equal to 0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I'm still confused about your explanation for the expected output. I just run your code the output is below:

```
[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
[0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
```

The reason that your function will return a list instead of multiplying one of the elements in the 2d matrix is that you use the index for the element in the 2d matrix in a wrong way.
Here is your code:

```
list = [[0.5],[0.3],[0.1]]

def funcOne(juv):    
    newAd = juv * list[0]
    return newAd

def funcTwo(ad,sen):
    newSen = (ad* list[1]) + (sen* list[2])
    return newSen

print(funcOne(3))
print(funcTwo(2,4))
```

In your code, when you use `juv * list[0]` in the function `funcOne`, it actually execute as `3 * [0.5]`, where `[0.5]` is the first element of the 2d matrix(list). You can run in the Python interpreter and find that the result of `3 * [0.5]` is `[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]`, which means it just replicate the elements in the list three times.

If you want to calculate like `[[0.5 * 3], [0.3], [0.1]]`, you should change a little bit of your code as following:

```
def funcOne(juv):    
    newAd = juv * list[0][0]
    return newAd

def funcTwo(ad,sen):
    newSen = (ad* list[1][0]) + (sen* list[2][0])
    return newSen
```

----------update

If you want to return the list like `[[1.5], [0.3], [0.1]]`. Change the code to

```
def funcOne(juv):    
    list[0][0] = juv * list[0][0]
    return list
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. My desired output for funcOne would be to have 3*0.5 = 1.5, where "0.5" is list[0]. I am unsure about how to edit my code in order to achieve this outcome.

Comment: If you only want to return the specific value `1.5`, you can use the function I edited above. If you want to return a list like [[1.5], [0.3], [0.1]]. You can change the code like below:

Comment: I was wondering if you were able to explain why I need list[0][0]?

Comment: Because the `list` here is a 2d matrix, or you can call it list of list. The elements of the `list` are also lists which are `[0.5]`, `[0.3]`, `[0.1]` respectively. If you want to retrieve the specific value like 0.5, or 0.3, or 0.1. You need to give the index to the child list: `[0.5]`, `[0.3]`, `[0.1]`. The same idea. If your list is like: `a = [[[0.1]], [[0.2]]]` and you want to get 0.1 instead of `[0.1]`, you need to use `a[0][0][0]`, because this is a list of list of list (3d matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Just return the `list` converted to `tuple`:

```
def funcOne(juv):    
    newAd = juv * list[0]
    return tuple(newAd) # convert to tuple
```

Same goes for `funcTwo`.

---

Then, to reproduce your desired output use:

```
>>> list = [[3], [6], [3]]
>>> print(funcOne(3))
(3, 3, 3)
>>> print(funcTwo(2, 4))
(6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3)
```