# Python - 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, floating-point

I get the error `'float' object is not subscriptable` when I run the following code: I believe that the error occurs since I am inputting the values of surRates using their list positions.

```
survRates = [[],[],[]]
newList = []
totalGens = 3

survRates[0] = 1.5
survRates[1] = 3.5
survRates[2] = 2.5

def gens():
    for i in range(totalGens):
        dataSet = []
        for j in range(3):
            dataSet.append([])
        newList.append(dataSet)
    print(newList)

def adultCalc(juvs):    
    newAdults = juvs * survRates[0][0]
    return newAdults

def senCalc(adults,sens):
    newSens = round((adults* survRates[1][0]) + (sens* survRates[2][0]),2)
    return newSens

generations()
newList[0][0] = 3.5
newList[0][1] = adultCalc(3)
newList[0][2] = senCalc(6,3)

print(newList)
```

When I run the same code by changing the **code below** to `survRates = [[1.5],[3.5],[2.5]]` instead of initializing the variables, it works.

```
survRates[0] = 1.5
survRates[1] = 3.5
survRates[2] = 2.5
```

My desired outcome is: `[[1.5, 3.5, 2.1], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]`, *which works if I use `survRates = [[1.5],[3.5],[2.5]]`*

Answer (score 1):

Is your desired result:

> `[[1.5, 3.5, 2.1], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]`?

or is it ?

> `[[[1.5], [3.5], [2.1]], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]`?

because the second one is an equal data structure more likely what you want.

Then you need to not do:

```
survRates[0] = 1.5
survRates[1] = 3.5
survRates[2] = 2.5
```

Instead do:

```
survRates[0] = []
survRates[0][0] = 1.5
survRates[0][1] = 3.5
survRates[0][2] = 2.5
```

or since you have very specific requirements: it looks like you had a typo in your question: this probably what you really wanted.

```
survRates = [[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]
survRates[0][0][0] = 1.5
survRates[0][0][1] = 3.5
survRates[0][0][2] = 2.5
```

That way each array will be an array with just one element... for I'm sure nefarious purposes.

You were not accurately describing what you wanted:

You wanted to set the position 0 (first element) in a list but not the list of survRates but instead the list in `survRates's` first element's list *(triply nested!)*. So for nested lists like survRates in order to access the first element of the first list you use: `an_array[0][0][0] =` just doing `an_array[0] =` or `an_array[0][0] =` will attempt to set the first element of survRates not survRates' first list or that list's first list.

This part generates: `[[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]`

```
def gens():
    for i in range(totalGens):
        dataSet = []
        for j in range(3):
            dataSet.append([])
        newList.append(dataSet)
    print(newList)
```

If you want further help here explain what's going on a bit deeper.

> newAdults = juvs * survRates[0][0]

Having a hardcoded `survRates[0][0]` will return a list not an element probably unlikely that you want to multiply juvs by a list with 3 mathematical elements probably you want `survRates[0][0][0]` there.

UPDATE ==>
Since they're saying they do particularly want it to have 1 array in the first data list and 3 arrays in each subsequent datalist:

gens() function should be modified:

```
def gens():
    for i in range(totalGens):
        dataSet = []
        for j in range(3):
            if i > 0:
                dataSet.append([])
        newList.append(dataSet)
    print(newList)
```

now we will have =>

```
[[], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]
```

This part in the beginning of your post will still give an error:

> ```
> survRates[0] = 1.5
> survRates[1] = 3.5
> survRates[2] = 2.5
> ```

But will work is:

```
 survRates[0][0] = 1.5
 survRates[0][1] = 3.5
 survRates[0][2] = 2.5
```

Comment: I would like to input the values 1.5,3.5 and 2.1 into the survRates like so `[[1.5, 3.5, 2.1], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]`.  [Here is a link to my previous question with the chosen answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250819/python-multiplying-an-element-from-2d-list). I think both of these questions are linked.

Comment: but why such an uneven data structure? sometimes you want a list with 3 elements and other times an list of 3 lists internally? are you sure that maybe a dictionary isn't preferred? like maybe: `survRates.adultRates = [1.5, 3.5, 2.1]` or something and then another key with `survRates.unknownKey = [[], [], []]` it seems like it will confuse you less often. To remember how often to nest: either way your gens() code makes a balanced list of lists because it generated in a simple loop... if you really want the first element in the list to be special exclude it from this loop.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I ended up using a simple loop like my gens code, and it seemed to work. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears to be how to initialize `survRates`.

First, you create a list the is three elements long, with each element being an empty list.

```
    survRates = [[],[],[]]
```

This means:

```
  survRates[0] = []
```

Next, each element of the list is changed from a list to a float, instead of appending the float element to the list.

```
  survRates[0] = 1.5
```

To create `survRates = [[1.5],[3.5],[2.5]]` change `survRates[0] = 1.5` to `survRates[0].append(1.5)`. This appends the number to the empty list.